# "I am divided. I am balanced. I am one."

Tags: syntax, translation-check, word-choice, english-to-latin-translation

I was hoping someone with more experience in Latin could help me confirm whether this translation is correct or not:

> *Ego sum dividitur. Ego sum libratum. Ego sum unum.*

Does this translate properly the following?

> I am divided. I am balanced. I am one.

Any help to correct it would be appreciated. Also the use of *Ego sum* even though not necessary on all parts was intentional for a repetitious effect. If you have a reason you believe I shouldn't phrase it that way I would like to hear it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can indeed say *ego sum X* for "I am X".
This, especially repeated, gives a lot of emphasis, but that is not inappropriate here.

The X should be a noun, an adjective, or something else that can be used as a predicative.
A personal form of a verb cannot be used as a predicative, so *ego sum divitur* is ungrammatical, much like "I am it is divided".
Instead, I recommend the participle *divisus*, "divided".

With the mentioned change your choice of words sounds appropriate.
The correct form depends on who speaks.
If the speaker is a male, a female, or an inanimate thing, you need the predicatives (none of which are nouns here) to be in masculine, feminine, or neuter, respectively.
This leads to three options:

> Ego sum divisus/divisa/divisum. Ego sum libratus/librata/libratum. Ego sum unus/una/unum.

If an implicit noun is understood, as in *ego sum [machina] divisa*, then the grammatical gender of the predicatives should match that of the noun.
The exact answer, as it often does, depends on the intended use context.